# NetBeans Platform: TopComponent - how to float by default? Custom Position opens separate window?

Tags: java, window, netbeans-platform

I have been trying to find a way to get all TopComponents in my applications to float by default. Meaning with a new build, when application starts up, Screen1TopComponent is assigned to Output position and is floating. Now, here I have 2 situations:

Screen1TopComponent is assigned to position "output" (one of the predefined ones) and when the App starts, it is docked. If I right click and choose float, the window will float, but won't disappear if I click on the main body of the app.

Screen2TopComponent is assigned to positon "smallWindow", which is a custom position I made that is floating by default, BUT when I launch the application, and I have docked Screen1 and floating Screen2, clicking on Screen1, will hide Screen2.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pedx.png

My questions are really this:

- How to make a TopComponent float by default? If the way is to create a custom position for it, like I did, then...
- Is there a way to make it float, but still be part of the application main frame, in a sense that it isn't displayed as 2 (like in screenshot).

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears I had to add the following line to my xml

```
<active-tc id="Screen2TopComponent"/>
```